# Testing a named route in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following route defined in routes.rb:

```
map.search 'fuzzyleads/search/:url', :controller => 'fuzzyleads', :action => 'search', :method => 'get'
```

The problem is that I cannot get this test to pass:

```
def test_search_route
  assert_generates "fuzzyleads/search/someurl", { :controller => "fuzzyleads", :action => "search", :url => "someurl" }
end
```

It does not like the url part, I get the following error:

> found extras <{:url=>"someurl"}>, not
>   <{}>

I have no idea why, can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried with a name other than 'url'? It is possible that it is conflicting with something internal to the routing process so it would be worth ruling that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output of `rake routes` would help us make a little better guess.  Here's how I tested using rails-2.3.8:

(1) Added your route as the second route in `config/routes.rb`

(2) Created the following rspec test:

```
it "should have valid route for fuzzyleads search" do
  route_for(:controller => 'fuzzyleads', :action => 'search', :url => 'someurl').should ==
    "/fuzzyleads/search/someurl"
end
```

But this failed with the following:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in 'FuzzyLeadsController should have valid route for fuzzyleads search'                   
No route matches "/fuzzyleads/search/someurl" with {:method=>:get}                                                  
If you're expecting this failure, we suggest {:get=>"/fuzzyleads/search/someurl"}.should_not be_routable
```

But when I removed the `:method` restriction everything worked successfully. Adding `:method => 'get'` wasn't sufficient to make the test pass.  I've seen similar failures when I've set conditions on routes that haven't been met, so I'd guess something similar is happening in your case.